# Formatting digits with comma separator in the TextField while typing

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use a comma separator in **Flutter** to format numbers in this format while typing: `"#,##,##,###.##"` but I don't want to include decimal places unless we type. The `ThousandsFormatter` class is formatting digits as expected, however, it is not allowing decimal input. I want to allow up to two decimal inputs when necessary without affecting the number formattings.

Here are some more examples of number formattings that I want with my code: `1,00,00,000` `15,000.34` `23,12,340.45`, `45,434.5`, `55,334` and so on. The digit inputs without decimals are working correctly.

It also has an another issue with comma. It adds the counting of comma to the `maxLength` of `TextField` input. Therefore to enter eight digits, I have set the `maxLength` to eleven.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is the code I have tried:

**class ThousandsFormatter:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

    class ThousandsFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
    @override
    TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final newText = newValue.text;
    if (newText.isEmpty) {
      return newValue;
    }
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    final String newTextFormatted = NumberFormat("#,##,##,###")
        .format(double.tryParse(newText.replaceAll(",", "")));
    if (newText == newTextFormatted) {
      return newValue;
    }
    selectionIndex += -(newText.length - newTextFormatted.length);
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newTextFormatted,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
        );
      }
    }
```

**main.dart**

```
    TextField(
    onEditingComplete: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodeY);
    },
    controller: principalController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Amount",
    isDense: true,
    counterText: "",     
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    maxLines: 1,
    maxLength: 11,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
    RegExp(r'^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$')),
    ThousandsFormatter(),
    ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var f = NumberFormat("#,##,##,###.##", "en_US");
        print(f.format(18));
        print(f.format(180000.00));
```

Comment: The code you provided is not working in my case.